# Using change of basis to construct system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

I've been studying linear algebra and have gotten the general understanding that when we are looking at a vector described by two separate bases, that we can generally apply:

$[u]_{T} = P_{S \rightarrow T}[u]_S$

Now, I am trying to apply this to this problem:

[image: The problem I am trying to solve now:]

Now, to address this problem I modeled $P_{s \rightarrow T}$ as
\begin{bmatrix}
    a       & b  \\
    c       & d  \\
\end{bmatrix}

Then, I set up my equations, fulfilling the inital equation, but hopefully giving me a system of equations to solve for $a, b, c, d$:

$\begin{bmatrix}    a       & b  \\    c       & d  \\\end{bmatrix} *\begin{bmatrix}    11 \\  5  \\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}    4   \\ 3  \\\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}    a       & b  \\    c       & d  \\\end{bmatrix} *\begin{bmatrix}    0 \\  -7  \\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}   1   \\ -2  \\\end{bmatrix}$

The answer is shown to be

[image]

However, from my system I can see that these are not the values that I would obtain, as from performing a bit of mental matrix multiplication, I can see that $b = -\frac{1}{7}$, and this is obviously wrong. This leads me to believe there is something wrong with my method.

I understand this is very simple math for many people in this community, but would really appreciate someone taking the time to point me in the right direction

Thank You,

David

Comment: Try $AP_s=P_t$ instead since you want to have matrix from S to T.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your equations the other way around: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}    a       & b  \\    c       & d  \\\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}    4   \\ 3  \\\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}    11 \\  5  \\\end{bmatrix} $$ and 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}    a       & b  \\    c       & d  \\\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}   1   \\ -2  \\\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}    0 \\  -7  \\\end{bmatrix} .
$$

---

For matrices:

When you express a linear operator as a matrix, there are two bases involved: one for the domain and one for the codomain. So if you are changing both bases, the change of basis is
$$[u]_T=P^{-1}[u]_SP.$$

Comment: Oh, strange my textbook didn't contain this. Thank you! That seemed to have worked :).

Comment: Actually, if I may follow up, the matrices are of different dimensions, and when trying to multiply the 2X1 matrix that is $[u]_{S}$ by a 2x2 matrix. If I circumvent this I am still left with a matrix that is 2X2 and must compare it to  $[u]_{T}$ which is a 2X1. Would you mind telling me how I could get around this?

Comment: So, what I said is correct, but when you change basis for a matrix. For vectors, you should multiply as you were trying, but you were doing it the wrong way. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Yep, that handles it. I thank you for your time!